# Setting a border for react native TextInput

Tags: react-native, react-native-text

Using React native 0.26,

My component is something like this

```
const Search = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <TextInput style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={(text) => console.log(text)} placeholder={"Enter Search Term"}/>
      </View>
    )
}
```

And my styles :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    flex : 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  textInput: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "stretch",
    borderRightWidth: 30,
    borderLeftWidth: 30,
    height: 50,
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
  }
})
```

The problems that I am facing are

1. The border right width and left width do not seem to have any effect and the placeholder text just begins on the left edge.
2. The background of TextInput is "grey" its the same as the View's background. I was expecting it to be white by default, (Feels transparent).
3. With iOS simulator how to bring up the keyboard, I would like to set `returnKeyType` and see how the keyboard looks (and have some code on `onSubmitEditing` and test).

Screenshot below :
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1 You cannot declare a specific border directly on the TextInput unless multiline is enabled (For example `borderLeftWidth` will not work unless `multiline={true}` is enabled but `borderWidth` will work), but you can just wrap the TextInput in a View and give it a border.

```
inputContainer: {
  borderLeftWidth: 4,
  borderRightWidth: 4,
  height: 70
},
input: {
  height: 70,
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  paddingLeft: 15,
  paddingRight: 15
}
```

2 You need to declare a `backgroundColor` for the TextInput.

3 To make the native keyboard show up, you need to go to the simulator menu and disconnect your hardware. Go to Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard, toggle it off.

Comment: the links which you specified is not working. @nader dabit

Answer (score 13):

As of `react-native: 0.61.5` you can directly set the `borderBottomWidth` on TextInput. Like below in inline style or if you want in separate style object.

> ```
>   style = {{borderBottomWidth : 1.0}}
> ```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default the boderWidth will be set for 0. So use `borderWidth : 5` defaults for (Top, Right, Bottom, Left).

If you want to asign width individually you have options like,

```
style = {{
borderStartWidth : 2
borderEndWidth : 3
borderTopWidth : 1
boderLeftWidth: 2
borderRightWidth: 3
borderBottomWidth : 4
}}
```